# trouble understanding with Map and map in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I tried to make some sort of convenient class (below) to hold folder and get file by using filename (string). This work as expect but one thing I don't understand is map part `Map(folder.listFiles map {file => file.getName -> file}:_*)`.

I place `:_*` there to prevent some kind of type incompatible but I don't know what does it really do. Also, what is `_*` and could I replace is with anything more specific ?

thanks

```
class FolderAsMap (val folderName:String){
  val folder = new File(folderName)
  private val filesAsMap: Map[String, File] = Map(folder.listFiles map 
                                          {file => file.getName -> file}:_*)

  def get(fileName:String): Option[File] = {
    filesAsMap.get(fileName)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

: _* is correct. Alternatively, you can use toMap:

```
folder.listFiles map {file => file.getName -> file}.toMap
```

`Map(...)` is method `apply` in object `Map`: `def apply [A, B] (elems: (A, B)*): Map[A, B]`. It has a repeated parameter. It is expected to be called with multiple parameters. The : _* is used to signal you are passing all the parameters as just one Seq argument.

It avoids ambiguities. In java, (where equivalent varargs are arrays instead of Seqs) there is a possible ambiguity, if a method `f(Object... args)` and you call it with `f(someArray)`, it could mean that args has just one item, with is someArray (so f receives an array of just one element, which its `someArray`), or args is `someArray` and f receives `someArray` directly). Java choose the second version. In scala, with a richer type system and `Seq` rather than `Array` the ambiguity may arise much more often, and the rule is that you always have to write  : _*  when passing all arguments as one, even when no ambiguity is possible, as in here, rather than a complex rule to tell when there is an actual ambiguity.

Comment: well, I'm not sure about java part. But from your explanation, :_* sounds a lot like calling function using * in python f(list*).

Comment: @Tg. yes, you may think of it this way.

Answer (score 1):

The `_*` makes the compiler pass each element of `folder.listFiles map { file => file.getName -> file}` as an own argument to `Map` instead of all of it as one argument.

---

In this case the `map` function creates a `Array` (because `folder.listFiles` returns that type). So if you write:

```
val files = folder.listFiles map { file => file.getName -> file }
```

...the returned type will be `Array[(String, File)]`. To convert this to a `Map` you will need to pass `files` one by one to the maps constructor using the `_*` (or use the method `toMap` like @didierd wrote):

```
val filesAsMap = Map(files : _*)
```